# ReasonML access JS record field

Tags: javascript, ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Say I have a global object called `Example`, which has a constructor such that `new Example()` returns an object with a key called `"Messaging"`

Say I have the following Reason/Bucklescript Code:

```
[@bs.deriving abstract] type example = {
  [@bs.as "Messaging"] messaging: string
};

type wrappedExample = Js.t(example);

[@bs.new] external exampleConstructor: unit => wrappedExample = "ExampleThing";

exampleConstructor()#messaging;
```

This results in:

```
This expression has type wrappedExample
It has no method messaging
```

Changing the last line to:

`exampleConstructor()##messaging` or `exampleConstructor().messaging` similiarly fails. What is the issue here? How can I access my javascript value?

https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=NoAQRgzgdAJgpgJwJYDckDsDmACAhpAFwVwGMCBdbAgTwAc5s4APXAW1oBsGBebAbwBQ2bKEhRcEbACIAsnAgRcmDJimVW8xcqwAubBCIqBAXwDcAgTXrYA7sVr0YAURbsu2XgCloBABTM2TjgASnMBUWh0OBtKZgJEdFwORlcggGEAe3QDBABXMgyEPVz0JAIPAD5be0cXQPdeKTq3OAAVAAsVKTCAlszsonyCQt9ggGINBSUVUyA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be conflating a bunch of things here that are similar, but don't really work together.

So first of all, `#` is used for accessing the field of an OCaml object. `##` is used to access the field of a `Js.t` object, which is not what you have here (I'll explain why in a minute).

`[@bs.deriving abstract]` is a different concept from `Js.t` and will not create an object type of any kind, but produces an *abstract type* (this is what `abstract` in the `bs.deriving` annotation hints at). An abstract type has no "structure" in itself, so you can't do anything with it directly. And wrapping it in `Js.t` does not make it a JS object type, just an abstract type wrapped in `Js.t` (a `Js.t` object type is specifically an OCaml object type wrapped in `Js.t`).

The key to this is that `[@bs.deriving abstract]` doesn't just create an abstract type, but also a number of functions that operate on it. For every field it creates a getter suffixed with `Get`, `messagingGet` in your case, and if mutable a setter suffixed with `Set`. There's also a creation function named after the type and with the fields as labeled arguments, so in your case you can create an object with `example(~messaging="whatever")`. See [the BuckleScript documentation](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/object) for details.

Here's a fixed version of your example:

```
[@bs.deriving abstract] type example = {
  [@bs.as "Messaging"] messaging: string
};

[@bs.new] external exampleConstructor: unit => example = "ExampleThing";

exampleConstructor() |> messagingGet;
```

If you think this is all very confusing, that's because it is. I have no clue what they're doing anymore, but it seems very messy to me too. I would recommend skipping `[@bs.deriving abstract]` entirely and instead create the abstract type and accessors yourself using ordinary `external`s. There's much less confusing magic and terrible naming of things that way.